# Access nested object dynamically by using array of string as a path

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement a generic method to access a nested object property dynamically.

The path to the property have to be in an array of string.

So to get the label the array of string would be `['type', 'label']`

I'm kinda stuck on this problem, any help ?

**Edit snipet : **

**Demo**

```js
var parent = {
  type: {
    id: "2",
    label: "3",
  }
};

function getNestedLabel(ids){
if (ids.length === 1) {
  return parent[ids[0]];
}
var result = parent;
for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  result = result[ids[i]];
}
return result;
  }

console.log(getNestedLabel(["type", "label"]));
```

Comment: what is the input parameter to `getNestedObject` and how does it access the `parent` object to traverse?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? https://www.npmjs.com/package/nested-property

Comment: Hi id is an array of strings right?

Comment: You may want to look into this https://lodash.com/docs/#get.

Comment: @blueren I can't use this kind of module because I'm working with an array of string and not a string with dots. The idea would be to construct this : parent['type']['id'] for example

Comment: @RahulRana Yes id is an array of string defining the path to the property

Comment: Related: [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6491463/4642212).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple approach would be to iterate the `keyArray` and also keep traversing the *object* with *keys* from `keyArray`

```
function getNestedObject( keyArr ){
    var tmp = parent; //assuming function has access to parent object here
    keyArr.forEach( function(key){
       tmp = tmp[key];
    });
    return tmp;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var parent = {
  type: {
    id: "2",
    label: "3",
  }
};

function getNestedObject(keyArr) {
  var tmp = parent; //assuming function has access to parent object here
  keyArr.forEach(function(key) {
    tmp = tmp[key];
  });
  return tmp;
}

console.log( getNestedObject( [ "type", "label" ] ) );
```

Comment: The method is in the parent object so ok. But it has to return the string value of the nested property and not the parent itself. The caller give the path and should get the string value in return. I don't know if I'm clear in my explanation

Comment: @An-droid Check the demo I have shared.

Comment: I tested and your solution is not working tmp is undefined at return

Comment: @An-droid Can you share a working fiddle of your attempt? Is the demo I have shared not working for you?

Comment: "run code snipet" is not working indeed. I integrated your method as it is with just 'this' instead of 'parent'. And as i'm using it in ngfor it's really bad for performances. I've updated my question with my current attempt

Comment: I updated a snipet, it kinda works but as I said it's not usable in my case. Used in ngfor it makes the UI lags as hell :/ I would need to save each nested properties to process it only one time and juste return it the other times ..

Comment: @An-droid I don't see why UI will lag because of this.

Comment: I don't either, but anyway this is another issue. You helped and your answer is not bad so I'll accept it thank you :)

Comment: More compact with `reduce`: `const getNestedObject = (parent, keyArr) => keyArr.reduce((currentObject, property) => currentObject?.[property], parent); getNestedObject({ type: { id: "2", label: "3" } }, [ "type", "label" ]);`.

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
getNestedObject(parent: any, id:string[]): string{

    let child = {...parent};
    let result: string;
    for(let i=0; i<id.length; i++){
        if( i !== id.length-1 ){
            child = child[id[i]]
        }
        else{
            result = child[id[i]]
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```