# Filter list by its item's property in javascript

Tags: javascript

I can filter a pure list by this:

```
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3]

function list_filter(list, value) {

  return list.filter(function (item) {
    if (item === value) {
      return true
    }
  })

}

console.log(list_filter(list, 1))  // there will print `[1, 1]`
```

But I have a further requirement of filter like bellow:

```
var a = [

  {a:'1', b:"2", c:3, d: {id:'d1'}},
  {a:'1', b:"2", c:3, d: {id:'d2'}},
  {a:'1', b:"2", c:3, d: {id:'d1'}},
  {a:'1', b:"2", c:3, d: {id:'d3'}},
  {a:'1', b:"2", c:3, d: {id:'d3'}},
  {a:'1', b:"2", c:3, d: {id:'d4'}}
]
```

I want to filter the list by `item.d.id`

I want to `list_filter` like this:

```
function list_filter(list, 'd.id', value) ... // the value is the filter id
```

or:

```
function list_filter(list, ['d', 'id'], value) ...
```

I mean,

```
list_filter(a, ['d', 'id'], 'd1')
```

to get the filtered list. the `['d', 'id']` maybe `['d', 'e', 'id']` or more long.

Comment: So what is your question? How to access nested properties given an array of strings as a path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access nested object dynamically by using array of string as a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47550857/access-nested-object-dynamically-by-using-array-of-string-as-a-path)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.filter` with a `reduce` inside that identifies the target value:

```js
var a=[{a:'1',b:"2",c:3,d:{id:'d1'}},{a:'1',b:"2",c:3,d:{id:'d2'}},{a:'1',b:"2",c:3,d:{id:'d1'}},{a:'1',b:"2",c:3,d:{id:'d3'}},{a:'1',b:"2",c:3,d:{id:'d3'}},{a:'1',b:"2",c:3,d:{id:'d4'}}];
const list_filter = (arr, keyArr, value) => (
  arr.filter(obj => (
    value === keyArr.reduce((currObj, key) => currObj[key], obj)
  )
));

console.log(list_filter(a, ['d', 'id'], 'd3'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the native [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method and add a `for ... of` loop that goes through your path :

```js
let data = [
  {a:'1', b:"2", c:3, d: {id:'d1'}},
  {a:'1', b:"2", c:3, d: {id:'d2'}},
  {a:'1', b:"2", c:3, d: {id:'d1'}},
  {a:'1', b:"2", c:3, d: {id:'d3'}},
  {a:'1', b:"2", c:3, d: {id:'d3'}},
  {a:'1', b:"2", c:3, d: {id:'d4'}}
];

const list_filter = (arr, path, val) => {
  return arr.filter(e => {
    let field = e;
    for(let currentPath of path) field = field[currentPath];
    return field == val;
  });
};

console.log(list_filter(data, ['d', 'id'], 'd1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a `.`-separated string of keys, or an array of keys, I'd advocate the approach of using a signature that accepts a function to select the value from each item like this:

```js
const a = [
  {a:'1', b:'2', c:3, d: {id:'d1'}},
  {a:'1', b:'2', c:3, d: {id:'d2'}},
  {a:'1', b:'2', c:3, d: {id:'d1'}},
  {a:'1', b:'2', c:3, d: {id:'d3'}},
  {a:'1', b:'2', c:3, d: {id:'d3'}},
  {a:'1', b:'2', c:3, d: {id:'d4'}}
]

function filter_list (array, selector, value) {
  return array.filter(
    item => selector(item) === value
  )
}

console.log(filter_list(a, o => o.d.id, 'd1'))
// or
console.log(filter_list(a, ({d:{id}}) => id, 'd1'))
```