# Construct an object from keys in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

For example if we have an existing object

```
const mainObject = {
  title: 'some title',
  topics: {
    topic1: {
      path: '',
      id: 1
    },
    topic2: {
      path: '',
      id: 2
    }
  }
}
```

and I have a function that gets array containing keys 
for example

```
const arrayOfKeys = ['topics', 'topic1'];

function getObjectByKeys(arrayOfKeys) {
  // problem is length of the array may change
  const myObject = mainObject[arrayOfKeys[0]][arrayOfKeys[1]];
  return myObject;
}
```

function should return

```
{
      path: '',
      id: 1
}
```

Comment: What should be the expected object output for keys you mentioned?
const arrayOfKeys = ['topics', 'topic1'];

Comment: You can loop over keys and/or values using `Object.keys()`, `Object.values()` and `Object.entries()`. But if every topic is going to be called topicX, with X being a numbers, might as well turn topics into an array so you can loop more easily.

Comment: it could be called anything not topic necessarily

Comment: My point is, once you have a collection of things, whatever they are, it's mostly beneficial to  make an array out of them so looping becomes very easy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access nested object dynamically by using array of string as a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47550857/access-nested-object-dynamically-by-using-array-of-string-as-a-path)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reduce` here. Initialise the accumulator with the main object and on each iteration of its callback return the value corresponding to current key.

```js
const mainObject = {
  title: 'some title',
  topics: {
    topic1: {
      path: '',
      id: 1
    },
    topic2: {
      path: '',
      id: 2
    }
  }
}

const arrayOfKeys = ['topics', 'topic1'];

function getObjectByKeys(arrayOfKeys) {
  return arrayOfKeys.reduce((a, el, i, arr) => {
    return a[el] || {};    
  }, mainObject);
}

console.log(getObjectByKeys(arrayOfKeys));
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be using the `forEach` loop.

```js
const mainObject = { title: 'some title', topics: { topic1: { path: '', id: 1 }, topic2: { path: '', id: 2 } } }
const arrayOfKeys = ['topics', 'topic1'];

function getObjectByKeys(arrayOfKeys) {
  let result = Object.assign({}, mainObject);
  arrayOfKeys.forEach(function(key){
    result = result[key];
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(getObjectByKeys(arrayOfKeys));
```

Another approach is to use `reduce` method by passing a `callback` function as argument.

```js
const mainObject = { title: 'some title', topics: { topic1: { path: '', id: 1 }, topic2: { path: '', id: 2 } } }
const arrayOfKeys = ['topics', 'topic1'];

getObjectByKeys = (arrayOfKeys) => {
  return arrayOfKeys.reduce((obj, item) => obj[item], mainObject);
}

console.log(getObjectByKeys(arrayOfKeys));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const mainObject = {
  title: 'some title',
  topics: {
    topic1: {
      path: '',
      id: 1
    },
    topic2: {
      path: '',
      id: 2
    }
  }
};
const arrayOfKeys = ['topics', 'topic1'];

var aa= arrayOfKeys.reduce((carry,value,index)=>{
             return carry[value];
        },mainObject);
        
console.log(aa);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use recursive.

```js
const mainObject = {
  title: 'some title',
  topics: {
    topic1: {
      path: '',
      id: 1
    },
    topic2: {
      path: '',
      id: 2
    },
    topic3: {
      path: 'more depth',
      subtopic: {
        path: '',
        id: 4
      },
      id: 3
    }
  }
}

const arrayOfKeys = ['topics', 'topic3', 'subtopic'];

function getObjectByKeys(arrayOfKeys, currentObj, index = 0) {
  if(index >= arrayOfKeys.length) {
    return currentObj;
  }
  return getObjectByKeys(arrayOfKeys, currentObj[arrayOfKeys[index]], index+1)
}

console.log(getObjectByKeys(arrayOfKeys, mainObject));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can edit your function as below and it will give you desired output.

```
function getObjectByKeys(obj, [first, ...rest]) {
  if(rest.length > 0 ) return getObjectByKeys(obj[first], rest) 
  else return obj[first]
}

getObjectByKeys(mainObject, ['topics', 'topic1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change topics into an array so finding any element becomes trivial.
The code is almost human readable now: "find entry with id 1 inside field_name of mainObject."

```js
const mainObject = {
  title: 'some title',
  topics: [
    { id: 1, path: 'first' },
    { id: 2, path: 'second' }
  ]
};
const field_name = 'topics';
const entry_to_find = 1;

const entry = mainObject[ field_name ].find( entry => entry.id === entry_to_find );
console.log( entry );
```