# Access Object with Array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

If I have an array:

```
const arr = ['this', 'is', 'my', 'test'];
```

How can I dynamically do

```
myObj[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]]
```

Comment: Related: [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6491463/4642212).

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+access+nested+properties+by+array+path) of [Access nested object dynamically by using array of string as a path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47550857/4642212).

Comment: it is not clear what you want. Do you want to map an array field by field into an object?

Comment: @Lynx242 i need to do this programmatically myObj['this']['is']['my']['test']

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for? [enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

```js
const arr = ['this', 'is', 'my', 'test'];
var Obj = arr.join(" ");
console.log(Obj)
```

--------------------------------please see this as updated ---------------------

```
const arr = ['this', 'is', 'my', 'test'];

var Obj = [];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  Obj.push([arr[i]])
}
```

Comment: actually i want to do this myObj[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]]
join will make it something like myObj[this is my test]
i want myObj['this']['is']['my']['test']

Comment: then you could do `var Obj = [[arr[0]],[arr[1]],[arr[2]]];`

Comment: yes exactly but i need to do this dynamically not manually

Comment: i updated in my previous answer